# XHR HEADhttp://localhost:4200/assets/Bootstrap/images/banners/megamenu-banner@2x.jpg

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, header, http-headers

I have tried to use Bootstrap template with Angular. After I setup the template everything works fine. But I'm getting error in my header showing some images not found. I have go through file and actually there's no file like the name showing in console.

After that I found that my image file names replaces with **@2x**. Can anyone tell me how to fix this. I have uploaded console error screenshot to get more idea Console log error image:
[image: Console log error image]

Comment: Is image present in assets/bootstrap/images/products/ or /banners or /flags path?

Comment: In my local system image is loaded perfectly with image name is test@1.jpg

Comment: yes.its present

Comment: have you included `2x` in any srcset in your code? `2x` images are for retina displays

Comment: i didnt. im using a bootstrap template i have purchased. if it  included how can i find it...?